# Getting started with Diffplex

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, diffplex

I want to highlight difference between two files in asp.net. After web search I chose Diffplex APi. I am a begineer. I need some guidance on how to implement it? I have added the reference librarys and that's all I could understand. There isn't any documentation of the Api. I haven't used Apis before.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple example from the "documentation" (i.e. the source code) that should get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DiffPlex;
using DiffPlex.DiffBuilder;
using DiffPlex.DiffBuilder.Model;
using System.Text;


namespace DiffPlexTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string oldText =  @"We the people
                of the united states of america
                establish justice
                ensure domestic tranquility
                provide for the common defence
                secure the blessing of liberty
                to ourselves and our posterity";
            string newText = @"We the peaple
                in order to form a more perfect union
                establish justice
                ensure domestic tranquility
                promote the general welfare and
                secure the blessing of liberty
                to ourselves and our posterity
                do ordain and establish this constitution
                for the United States of America";

            var d = new Differ();
            var builder = new InlineDiffBuilder(d);
            var result = builder.BuildDiffModel(oldText, newText);

            foreach (var line in result.Lines)
            {
                if (line.Type == ChangeType.Inserted)
                {
                    sb.Append("+ ");
                }
                else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Deleted)
                {
                    sb.Append("- ");
                }
                else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Modified)
                {
                    sb.Append("* ");
                }
                else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Imaginary)
                {
                    sb.Append("? ");
                }
                else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Unchanged)
                {
                    sb.Append("  ");
                }

                sb.Append(line.Text + "<br/>");
            }

            ViewData["old"] = oldText;
            ViewData["new"] = newText;
            ViewData["result"] = sb.ToString();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Great -- I built a diff tool on top of DiffPlex that works pretty well so I think you'll have good luck with it.

Comment: Does Diffplex have a native merge option?

Comment: I don't believe so. I only used it to provide a visual diff to aid in rollbacks.

Comment: That's what I thought, started writing my own. Thanks again :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to detect Modified lines for me, it just treats them as both an Inserted AND Deleted line. Odd

Comment: Hmm, sorry it is not working for you. Post a SO question with your source and link to it here and I could take a look.